# Adding component dynamically ViewContainerRef is undefined

Tags: angular

In Parent Component.ts

```
  @ViewChild('dynamic', {
    read: ViewContainerRef
  }) viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;
```

In HTML code

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-container" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of testSelector" cdkDrag>
    <div class="title">{{item.key}}</div>
    <div class="content" [innerHTML]="item.value | safeHtml">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<ng-template #dynamic></ng-template>
```

This work fine but when nested inside dive

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-container" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of testSelector" cdkDrag>
    <div class="title">{{item.key}}</div>
    <div class="content" [innerHTML]="item.value | safeHtml">
       <ng-template #dynamic></ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

viewContainerRef is undefined?

Component.ts

```
@Component({
 ....
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('dynamic', {
    read: ViewContainerRef
  }) viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(@Inject(Service) private service) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.service.setRootViewContainerRef(this.viewContainerRef);
    this.service.addDynamicComponent();
  }
}
```

and service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class Service {
    factoryResolver: any;
    rootViewContainer: any;
    constructor(
        @Inject(ComponentFactoryResolver)
        factoryResolver) {
        this.factoryResolver = factoryResolver;
    }
    setRootViewContainerRef(viewContainerRef) {
        this.rootViewContainer = viewContainerRef;
    }
    addDynamicComponent() {
        const factory = this.factoryResolver
            .resolveComponentFactory(JobDashComponent);
        const component = factory
            .create(this.rootViewContainer.parentInjector);
        this.rootViewContainer.insert(component.hostView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to access the `viewContainerRef`?

Comment: In component.ts corresponding to this html code

Comment: Could you please add it here too?

Comment: I will add only the necessary content this component

Comment: It depends on where you are trying to access the `viewContainerRef`.

Comment: I supouse you need ViewChildren (you has severals "dynamic") and use in ngAfterViewInit. see that you need subscribe to changes

Comment: Don't you overwrite the `ng-template` with the innerHTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `viewContainerRef` is undefined because you overwrite it with the `[innerHTML]` on it's parent tag

Instead of `[innerHTML]` you can use this

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-container" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of testSelector" cdkDrag>
    <div class="title">{{item.key}}</div>
    <div class="content">
       {{item.value | safeHtml}}
       <ng-template #dynamic></ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Select more elements with same `#id`:**

If you want to select every element with a specific `#id` then you can use `QueryList`.

The syntax would look like this

```
@ViewChildren('dynamic') viewContainerRefList: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;
```

Then you can then work with it like with normal array if you apply `.toArray()` on it.

`const array = viewContainerRefList.toArray();`

Comment: for example ngFor iterate over by Array length = 3 but only first element contains ng-template. Why this content is not added to all elements from array?

Comment: You mean why only the first `ng-template` is accessed by `@ViewChild()`?

Comment: I thought about it